# JavaScript/C#/VS Remove IntelliSense Auto Complete Options

Tags: javascript, c#, visual-studio-2015, intellisense

I was wondering if anyone knew how to delete specific entries within IntelliSense's autocomplete function? Such as the below, I accidentally hit enter too fast and it stored a partial variable name as an entry (since I'm working with JavaScript via Ajax and accessing the objects properties). I looked into C#'s/JavaScripts's options for IntelliSense and only saw the option to disable the list entirely. I'm hoping I can just remove the one entry. If worse comes to worse, is there a way to clear the entire list and start over?

[Snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GvmhB.png)

Thanks for the help! :)

Comment: Are those `ExitCode, Exitmes and ExitMessage` public properties of data object?

Comment: Intellisense auto complete should be pulling from the definition of the object, not a list of things that you have typed in.  Are you sure that `data` doesn't have a member called `Exitmes`?

Comment: As far as I know, the list members is a list of valid members from a type (or namespace) appears after you type a trigger character (for example, a period (.) in managed code or :: in C++), please check this：https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hcw1s69b.aspx and this depends on your code of the method 'PopupShowAlert', you can move the cursor on the 'ExitCode', 'Exitmes', 'ExitMessage' to check the Quick Info.

Comment: @Win The ExitCode and ExitMessage are both public properties, the "ExitMes" property doesn't actually exist within the object (http://imgur.com/a/z9s2J - object properties).

Comment: @BJ Myers see my answer to Win.

Comment: @Sara-MSFT Thank you for the link! It got me closer but still not cigar. I wasn't able to find a way to delete it from there :\

Comment: Also apologies, I updated my question as it probably would make more sense if I included the fact as to why there is a "false" property in Intellisense (since it should be showing me the class properties) and why I wanted to remove it - it's because it's more so JavaScript that is working with a C# object passed through ajax :).

Comment: @sys_adm_dev, the lists members are auto created, you can try to choose 'Exitmes' and move the cursor on the 'Exitmes' and right click, then choose 'Go to Definition F12' to check where is this property be defined, if you can find it and remove this definition to make it disappear from the list members.